# Why can I not switch scenes in my unity2d iPhone game?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to switch screens but it can't, I have browsed multiple forums and none of the solutions have worked. The code I am using is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void GoToGameScene()
    {
        //Application.LoadLevel(1);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

This is my "GameMasterScript" which is attached to my canvas that my button is under, I have also tried attaching it to the main camera but that doesn't seem to work as well.

The following are screenshots of my canvas, button, and my build settings.
[image: Canvas][image: Build Settings][image]

Comment: What currently happens?

Comment: @SamuelG Right now when I click on the button, nothing. It just keeps me in the same scene

Comment: Did u test the function without the button? (Just by running it in the script)

Comment: @figbar I just tried that, and it does switch scenes. So it has to do with the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue I ran into here was dragging an image and adding a button component to it, which made it not work. Simply adding a button to the canvas UI then putting the image on the button allowed it to work properly

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that happened, because your code looks fine.